# Counting endmarks in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string of sentences and want to count all of what I consider to be end marks.

Those endmarks include: **.  ?  !  *  _**

*[so a period, question mark, exclamation mark, asterisks  or underscore]*

I want the fastest way to count those occurrences using base R.  So for instance the following  string would have a count of 6.

```
x <- "I like to play.  Do you?  Yes I do!  Go*  I didn't say it, but will. I wanted to but_"
```

and this string would have a count of 4:

```
y <- "I like it!  Do you?  Look*  Where are you go_"
```

The solution should use base R as this is for a package.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the *fastest* way, but very easy:

```
> x <- "I like to play.  Do you?  Yes I do!  Go*  I didn't say it, but will. I wanted to but_"
> y <- "I like it!  Do you?  Look*  Where are you go_"
> 
> length(gregexpr("[.?!*_]", x)[[1]])
[1] 6
> length(gregexpr("[.?!*_]", y)[[1]])
[1] 4
```

**UPDATES**

`gregexpr` returns `-1` if there is no match, so you need check it. This will be correct:

```
 sum(gregexpr("[.?!*_]", x)[[1]] > 0)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works very well.  For my purposes it's very fast.  I'll accept as soon as I can.  Thank you +1

Comment: In addition to this, you could do them both at once: sapply(gregexpr("[.?!*_]", c(x, y)), length).

Comment: Given kohske's update, which I completely overlooked, too, you could try this: sapply(gregexpr("[.?!*_]", c(x, y, "this has no match")), function(elem) length(elem[elem != -1]))

Comment: @BryanGoodrich I think ` function(elem) sum(elem != -1)` will be faster. The difference may be very slight though.

Comment: I agree. It saves the time of not doing a vector search to subset the list element. Instead, you sum the TRUEs to an appropriate boolean vector on the element (with TRUE = 1, giving us an accurate count).

Answer (score 0):

Check out stringr:::string_count.  It's fair to import other useful functions in your package.